# How to submit form, programatically with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have form, which when is submitted, is making ajax POST request, posting data fetched from form. Form is quite straight forwards.

```
<form id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="domain" id="field1">
    <input type="submit" name="my-submit" id="my-submit" value="Submit Form" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
    <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>-->
</form>
```

Then #response div where returned content is loaded.

```
# HTML code ...
<div class="modal-body" id="response">
    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
</div>
# HTML code ...
```

And finally JavaScript...

```
$('#form1').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'check.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(),

        success: function (data) {
            //console.log(data);

            $('#response').html(data);
            $("#myModal").modal();
        }
    });
});
```

But then, I want to check in my index.php script, where all these above is, if is $domain variable passed in URL, like **yoursite.com?domain=domain.com**, and if is, to call submit(); function programatically with this code:

```
if(isset($_GET['domain'])) {
    $domain = $_GET['domain'];
    echo $domain;
    echo "
        <script>
            $('#form1').submit();
        </script>
    ";
    //exit();
}
```

Problem is, that nothing happens. How to achieve desired behaviour?

Comment: What does the `console` says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do that. There is no reason to serve a page to the client, fill a form automatically and post back to the server.

Instead you should check if `$_GET['domain']` domain is set and if it is, you should include your `check.php` file directly. And you should adapt `check.php` to handle both POST and GET parameters.

This would save you a round-trip to the client and does not rely on the client having javascript enabled.

Comment: Normally I use POST, and AJAX to post the form data to check.php. Another user case scenario is when user pass variable to URL, like yoursite.com/domain.com (will be rewritten with mod rewrite), but I don't check.php to return data, instead I wan't my index.php returns data. So my index.php will handle both $_GET and $_POST, because my check.php returns plain data to my modal window in index.php.

Comment: @AlanKis Assuming that `check.php` echoes the data when you make a POST request, you just need to make sure it stores the variable in case of a GET request (when it is included) so that you can use that variable to generate your modal on page load.

Comment: Brilliant idea, Jeroen. I will echo data in my #response div, but I am not sure how to trigger my modal window with $("#myModal").modal(); , or which event to trigger it, or trigger it programatically.

Comment: @AlanKis That does not change, you trigger it the same way you do now but when the DOM is ready (standard jQuery) and if  `$_GET['domain']` is set, like you were trying to do with your automatic submit. The code to open your modal window does not require an ajax call to be made.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="domain" id="field1">
    <input type="submit" onclick="return call();" value="Submit Form">
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function call()
{
  //ajax code;
  return true;//are your want form submit
  return false;// are your want cannot form submit
}
</script>
```

Don't forget to put return